# simplest way to run a tool inside a users RDP session from linux using only the commandline

Tags: linux, windows, remote, winrm, psexec

I tried evilwinrm which works well to use a remote shell but smh I cannot directl ylaunch a GUI app inside of a users session.

It would also be ok to use ssh serve ron the Wndows RDS server or soemthign like that.
just the faster the better.

The general idea is to run a GUI-Tool inside a users session.

I have both an administrator password and the users password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way, but it is a bit tricky.

First you have to install the sshd on the Windows system:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse

Then you can pass a command from your Linux system to the Windows system via `ssh`, example:

```
ssh user@windows "dir"
```

- `dir` is the Windows equivalent to `ls`

If this works, you create a task to start your program via `schtasks`, example:

```
schtasks /create /tn test /tr C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe /sc once
```

- `/tn` Task name
- `/tr` Task run (executable of your program)
- `/sc` Typ (daily, weekly, once)

More information: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/schtasks-create

This task can then be executed "remotely" via Linux:

```
ssh user@windows "schtasks /run /tn test"
```

All other tests on my part have ended in either a shell session freeze or non-starting programs (for UI programs), but there may be better ways to make this work, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59880794/starting-gui-programs-via-openssh-on-windows